# Find route variables from attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to autofill ViewContext with 1 parameter of routes, however sometimes it is in query, sometimes it is in Url.

When in query, it is easy to get the parameter using `req.Query.TryGetValue(key, out StringValues val)`.
However I am looking for a way to capture the route parameter when it is like this:

```
[PrefillViewContext("postId")]
[HttpGet("/Post/{postId}")]
public IActionResult DisplayPost(Guid postId) {}
```

Is there a way to get this `postId` value outside of the method body, and use it in the attribute just above? (or in an attribute at class level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get action parameters using [ActionExecutingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) by inheriting `ActionFilterAttribute`.You could get all RouteData from the context.

```
public class PrefillViewContextAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var postId = context.ActionArguments["PostId"];
    }

}
```

Comment: At the end I used another method because I used more complex routes, but this was working as expected. Thanks.